# Combinations of 4 variables with 3 values each

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, combinations

I'm pretty new to Excel and am trying to find a way to automatically generate all possible combinations (order not important) of 4 variables (A, B, C, D) with 3 values (1, 2, 3) each.

So there are only 12 possible variable+values:

A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3, D1, D2, D3

Each combination must have one instance of each variable.

For example:

A1, B2, C3, D1
A2, B3, C1, D3

There are 81 different combinations, and I want to put them in 81 rows and then drag a formula down the next column to apply to each row.

Is there any formula in excel to do that? I found one formula but it only lists the 12 combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might use Base to generate the numbers then concatenate them with A,B,C and D:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,{"A","B","C","D"}&MID(BASE(ROW()-1,3,4),{1,2,3,4},1)+1)
```

I have tested it in Excel 365 so far.

[image]

Also works in Excel 2019.

**EDIT**

So in Excel 2010 you wouldn't have textjoin (Excel 2019) or base (Excel 2013) and would have to do it like this (effectively doing your own conversion to base 3):

```
="A"&QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,27)+1&",B"&QUOTIENT(MOD(ROW()-1,27),9)+1&",C"&QUOTIENT(MOD(ROW()-1,9),3)+1&",D"&MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1
```

If you had Excel 365, you could use Base and Sequence and do it like this a bit shorter as a spill formula:

```
=LET(x,BASE(SEQUENCE(81,1,0),3,4),"A"&MID(x,1,1)+1&",B"&MID(x,2,1)+1&",C"&MID(x,3,1)+1&",D"&MID(x,4,1)+1)
```

Comment: The question is tagged with Excel 2010.

Comment: Thanks  - my answers are rubbish these days! So Excel 2010 doesn't have textjoin.

Answer (score 0):

@GSerg  #Excel 2010  A1

[image]

```
=REPT(TEXT(SUM(INT(MOD((ROW(A1)+{26,8,2,0})/{27,9,3,1}-1,3)+1)*10^{3,2,1,0}),"\A0\,\B0\,\C0\,\D0"),ROW()<82)
```